# How do i show and hide details on a single item on click

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, hide, dropdown, show

> So id like to just click the name and the rest of the details will
>   just drop down on that single
>        customer order, thanks

[image]

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of AllOrders; let i = index;">
<ion-card-header type="button">
  <ion-icon name="arrow-down"></ion-icon>
  {{item.customerName}}
</ion-card-header>

<ion-card-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-label>Customer Details</ion-label>
    <p>{{item.customerNumber}}</p>
    <p>{{item.customerEmail}}</p>
    <p>{{item.customerAddress}}</p>
    <ion-label>Product Details</ion-label>
    <p>{{item.productBrand}}</p>
    <p>{{item.productType}}</p>
    <p>{{item.productCode}}</p>
    <p>{{item.productColor}}</p>
    <p>{{item.productSize}}</p>
    <p>{{item.dateOfOrder}}</p>
    <p>Ordered By {{item.salesPerson}}</p>
    <p>Status: {{item.status}}</p>

  </ion-list>
  <ion-button (click)="DeleteOrder()">Delete</ion-button>

</ion-card-content>
```

Comment: Im using angular and Ionic and have tried a few things but im missing something and cant figure it out

Comment: Please try my answer

Answer (score 2):

Define a `bool` property in your component and based on that show or hide details.

```
public showDetails: bool = false;
```

using `*ngIf="showDetails"` in your html like this.

```
<ion-card-content>
  <ion-list *ngIf="showDetails">
    <ion-label>Customer Details</ion-label>
    <p>{{item.customerNumber}}</p>
    <p>{{item.customerEmail}}</p>
    <p>{{item.customerAddress}}</p>
    <ion-label>Product Details</ion-label>
    <p>{{item.productBrand}}</p>
    <p>{{item.productType}}</p>
    <p>{{item.productCode}}</p>
    <p>{{item.productColor}}</p>
    <p>{{item.productSize}}</p>
    <p>{{item.dateOfOrder}}</p>
    <p>Ordered By {{item.salesPerson}}</p>
    <p>Status: {{item.status}}</p>

  </ion-list>
  <ion-button (click)="DeleteOrder()">Delete</ion-button>

</ion-card-content>
```

And finally add an `click` to the name `icon-icon` like this:

```
<ion-card-header type="button" (click)="toggleDetails()">
  <ion-icon name="arrow-down"></ion-icon>
  {{item.customerName}}
</ion-card-header>
```

In your `Component` toggle it simply like this:

```
toggleDetails() {
   this.showDetails = !this.showDetails;
}
```

For adding some animation you can use css transition whatever you want or use third party lib like animate.css or Angular animation feature.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for you answer but ive tried this, i should have been clearer but there are other orders , and when i apply this method and click the header, All the orders open and close

Comment: im using an ngFor to load in the orders

Comment: <ion-card *ngFor="let item of AllOrders; let i = index;">

Comment: Oh, Got it. The best way is that you add another ```bool``` property to each ```order``` and on the toggle function send that e.g ```is_shown``` and check by that.

Comment: I create a simple version in the next answer for you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ewxtd

Answer (score 0):

In your typescript
`showDetails: boolean= false;`

In your html

```
<ion-card-header type="button" (click)="showDetails = !showDetails;">
  <ion-icon name="arrow-down"></ion-icon>
  {{item.customerName}}
</ion-card-header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can create a virtual property. This will help you to toggle your views

### html

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of AllOrders; let i = index;">
<ion-card-header type="button" ***(click)="toggleView(item)"***>
  <ion-icon name="arrow-down"></ion-icon>
  {{item.customerName}}
</ion-card-header>
<ion-card-content ****ngIf="item.showMore"***>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-label>Customer Details</ion-label>
    <p>{{item.customerNumber}}</p>
    <p>{{item.customerEmail}}</p>
    <p>{{item.customerAddress}}</p>
    <ion-label>Product Details</ion-label>
    <p>{{item.productBrand}}</p>
    <p>{{item.productType}}</p>
    <p>{{item.productCode}}</p>
    <p>{{item.productColor}}</p>
    <p>{{item.productSize}}</p>
    <p>{{item.dateOfOrder}}</p>
    <p>Ordered By {{item.salesPerson}}</p>
    <p>Status: {{item.status}}</p>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-button (click)="DeleteOrder()">Delete</ion-button>
</ion-card-content>
```

### in your .ts file

```
 public toggleView(item){
       item.showMore = !item.showMore
 }
```

Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution based on your comment for different show/hide for each component. Here is a simple sample for you:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ewxtd

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
    data = [
    {
      name: "Name 1", 
      is_shown: true
    },
    {
      name: "Name 2", 
      is_shown: true
    },
    {
      name: "Name 3", 
      is_shown: true
    },
    {
      name: "Name 4", 
      is_shown: true
    },
    {
      name: "Name 5", 
      is_shown: true
    }
  ];

  toggleShowName( is_shown, i ) {
    this.data.map(( _ , index ) => { if (index == i ) { _.is_shown = !_.is_shown }} )
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<h1>Simple Accordian Test</h1>

<div class="c-card" *ngFor="let d of data; let i = index;">
  <div class="name-container">
    <div class="cursure" (click)="toggleShowName(d.is_shown, i)" *ngIf="d.is_shown">+</div>
    <div class="cursure" (click)="toggleShowName(d.is_shown, i)" *ngIf="!d.is_shown">-</div>
    <div class="name" *ngIf="d.is_shown">
          {{d.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.css:

```
.c-card {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.cursure {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```